# ios developer certificated renewed, but it still said the certificated will expire after April 6, 2011

Tags: iphone

I have renew the ios developer certificate, 
it said that Your membership is set to expire on Apr 05, 2012. 
but when I check 'Current Distribution Certificate' Expiration Date  is Apr 6, 2011

How can I do to adjust the expire date of 'Distribution Certificate'?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the "Distribution Certificate" expires you can just renew it (for free), or even renew it before it expires. The expiration date of the distribution certificate has nothing to do with your actually membership. Apple chooses to have the distribution certificates expire rather quickly.

Comment: Do you mean invoke and request new certificate?

Comment: I believe that xcode might do it for you automatically now, but you can also go to the iOS Provisioning Portal and select "Renew" next to your provisioning profile.

Comment: The "Renew" button is for the mobile provision. How do you renew the "Distribution Certificate"? I couldn't find any option to do that in the iOS Provisioning Portal...

Comment: On the "distribution" tab you should be able to click on "Modify". Then select the drop down or something and select the same thing. You should then be able to press "Submit" and get a new certificate. That probably isn't the official way but it should work.